# How do I display the tabs in the query window in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, tabs, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio crashed on me due to plug-ins that we use (source control/schema/data compare, etc) and I had to reset it to defaults.

But now, every time I click on `New Query` the query window opens *without tabs*.

How do I open it *with* tabs?

Comment: Tools\Options\Environment\General\Tabbed Documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Hamlet Hakobyan's answer here so I can close out this question.

Answer:

```
Tools\Options\Environment\General\Tabbed Documents
```